# Logstash seems to be ingesting data with an incorrect timestamp?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am looking at the timestamp data for logstash and it seems to be off by 4 hours.  Likewise, during ingestion, I have a datetime:  `yyyyMMdd HH:mm` which is local to EST (New York) but is being conveyed as off by this same 4 hours.

I am not sure how logstash determines the current time, but i was thinking it mightve been specific to the host machine?  When looking at my machine, running `date` returns *Mon Oct 19 17:32:25 UTC 2020* which is a 4 hour difference from me currently ( 13:32 ), but the machine is accurate.

What I am thinking is that somehow there is a misinterpretation of the @timestaamp object on this logstash machine.  My recent Logstash ingested object is showing: *Oct 19, 2020 @ 09:33:00.000* which is 4 hour different.

I presumed that timestamp is set in logstash and not in elastic, but i can see that somehow there may be some sort of misinterpretation.

I am currently using the most up to date docker containers, which are all 7.9.2.   The ingested data timestamp is incorrect, and likewise, I noticed that some ingested data us being ingested at the above format but has no set datetime to adjust.

My desired end goal is to: Fix this discrency and then index the data on the timestamp reported and not the time of the curl request.

Ingested Data:

```
// http://realtime.portauthority.org/bustime/api/v3/getvehicles?key=hC5Di7VSYU3hjmw2gAqHtKdec&rt=65,67,69,7,71,71A,71B,71C,71D,74&format=json

{
  "bustime-response": {
    "vehicle": [
      {
        "vid": "6141",
        "rtpidatafeed": "Port Authority Bus",
        "tmstmp": "20201019 11:53",
        "lat": "40.45320129394531",
        "lon": "-79.7513656616211",
        "hdg": "176",
        "pid": 7788,
        "rt": "67",
        "des": "Downtown",
        "pdist": 0,
        "dly": false,
        "spd": 0,
        "tatripid": "9333",
        "origtatripno": "11348066",
        "tablockid": "067 -066",
        "zone": "",
        "mode": 0,
        "psgld": "HALF_EMPTY"
      }
    ],
    "error": [
      {
        "rt": "65",
        "msg": "No data found for parameter"
      },
      {
        "rt": "7",
        "msg": "No data found for parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

JSON Entry from Kibana:

```
{
  "_index": "transit-pittsburgh-2020.10.19",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "y60WQnUBgX7z6iMwvAaJ",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2020-10-19T14:19:00.000Z",
    "bustime-response": {
      "error": [
        {
          "msg": "No data found for parameter",
          "rt": "65"
        },
        {
          "msg": "No data found for parameter",
          "rt": "7"
        },
        {
          "msg": "No data found for parameter",
          "rt": "71"
        }
      ],
      "vehicle": {
        "rtpidatafeed": "Port Authority Bus",
        "pdist": 72453,
        "tablockid": "067 -066",
        "hdg": "66",
        "vid": "6141",
        "lat": "40.433110918317524",
        "rt": "67",
        "dly": false,
        "origtatripno": "11348056",
        "bk_tmstmp": "20201019 14:19",
        "tatripid": "9249",
        "mode": 0,
        "tmstmp": "20201019T14:19",
        "pid": 7294,
        "psgld": "FULL",
        "lon": "-79.7984379359654",
        "spd": 20,
        "zone": "",
        "geo_location": "40.433110918317524,-79.7984379359654",
        "des": "CCAC Boyce"
      }
    },
    "@version": "1"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-10-19T14:19:00.000Z"
    ],
    "bustime-response.vehicle.tmstmp": [
      "2020-10-19T14:19:00.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1603117140000
  ]
}
```

One thing i did noticed was that the Date converstion for bustime-response.vehcile.tmstmp is creating an ISO date as UTC when the ingested date was a simple local `yyyyMMdd HH:mm` format which I need to turn into EST Timezone.

Comment: Logstash sets the timestamp using the host time, if you do not specify that this time has a timezone offset, it will be considered as a UTC time since elasticsearch stores all dates in UTC. When using Kibana it will use the browser time per default and shows the correspondent time in your timezone. Where are you seeing the difference? Can you share an example of the log you are ingesting and your pipeline configuration?

Comment: Yes I can share it.  for sure. ill post it in a few minutes

Comment: @leandrojmp added a dump of ingested data vs the json representation output in kibana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are using the `date` filter with the field `tmstpm` to create the `@timestamp` fields.

The format `yyyyMMdd HH:mm` of the `tmstpm` field does not have any information about the offset from UTC, so if you simple use the `date` filter with this field without specifying that this time has a offset, it will be treated as a UTC time.

Using your example, `20201019 11:53`

```
date {
    match => ["tmstmp", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm"]
}
```

Losgtash will create the `@timestamp` field as `2020-10-19T11:43:00Z`, and in your timezone this time is `2020-10-19T07:43:00Z`, which is wrong.

You need to tell logstash that your original time field is in a different timezone from UTC.

```
date {
    match => ["tmstmp", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm"]
    timezone => "America/New_York"
}
```

This way the `@timestamp` field will be created with the value `2020-10-19T15:43:00Z` which is the UTC time when your local time is 11:43.

You can also use `timezone => "-0400"`

Comment: This is a great, fantastic answer.